# Copy file to remote directory out of my user's home directory on the server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp, remote

I want to copy a file directly to a remote folder out of my home directory on the server.
Let my username be john.
The server is structured as follows:

```
/
|    users/
|    |     john/
|          |
|    |     other_user/
|    data/
|    |
|    other_dir/
```

I want to do the following:

```
copy /path/to/file/on/my/local/machine /data/
```

Please take in mind that I have all access permissions on the directory /data/.

**Edit:**

I tried the following but I got **"scp: /data/: No such file or directory"**

```
scp /path/to/file/on/my/local/machine john@domain.com:/data/
```

**Edit 2:**

I used to do the following and this works:

```
scp /path/to/file/on/my/local/machine john@domain.com:~/file
mv ~/file /data/file
```

But I want to do it in a single step (if it is possible), because I have to wait twice for large files (one time for it to move from my local computer to my home directory on the server and the other for the file to move from my home directory on the server to the data directory.

**Edit 3:**
My home directory is under /users.
data directory exists of course (its real name is data1)
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact output from the scp command. Don't paraphrase it.

Comment: @Kenster done! I added the full error message

Comment: There is no directory `/data` on the server. Without the actual in- and output and a real `tree` or `ls /` it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: @pLumo please see edit 2 that I posted. /data directory exists of course.

Comment: Your title says copy. Your question says move. Which is it? Please [edit] your question for consistency

Comment: "_/data directory exists of course._" There's no "of course" here - we can't see over your shoulder and if you don't tell us we can't know.

Comment: Your edit 2 doesn't make sense. You presumably ran the scp on your client to push the file to the server. So you should have performed the mv on the server instead of the client - but that's not at all obvious from the way you've written it.

Comment: Is john@domain.com really the server, or just a slow way of accessing your own client? I'm starting to wonder if `/data` is actually a network mounted filsystem on your client.

Comment: @roaima it is really the server!

Comment: What does the picture in edit 3 show? Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: @roaima my third edit shows the list of directories under the root directory.

Comment: The problem is, that you leave out or obfuscate details, which seem to be part of the problem. If everything is normal, your `scp` command would work.

Answer (score 1):

The server has a directory `/data1` that you keep referencing as `/data`. There is no `/data`: these are two totally separate names.

Fix your typo and the problem will go away

Comment: I only named it data **in this post** but (of course) I use **data1** when typing the command.

Comment: Look. We're trying to help you but the sands keep shifting. Ask a real question with real data. Or if there is some vital reason why you have to name `/data1` as `/data` please be completely self-consistent. If you use `/data1` when typing the command why not do that in your question too?

Comment: Like I said already, there is no "of course" - we can't see over your shoulder and if you don't tell us we can't know

Comment: I know that all of you guys are trying to help me and thank you for that. I gave the real scenario and just changed the domain name and the target directory. I am **self-consistent** because I always use the name **data** in my explanation.

Comment: apparently using fake names doesn't make me **self-consistent**, so I want to say that I used **data** as an alias for data1, file as an alias for **model_final.pth**, domain as an alias for my university's domain, and john as an alias for my name so you can guess that john@domain.com doesn't really exist (of course).

Comment: "_I always use the name `data` in my explanation_" - no you don't. You've now introduced `/data1`